# Is there any way I can use famo.us animation for an existing div

Tags: famo.us

I have div and menus already,
what I need is famo.us matrix animation,
is there a way, 
I can use the existing element to do animation,
or is there any alternative.

I haven't created the div from famous,
and in that case I am sure I won't be able to manipulate with famo.us

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just import/require famous/transitions/Transitionable, and animate any number you want, then use it's get() method to get your value and continuously set the value of whatever you want to animate. You can use a setInterval to continuously get the value(s) and set some CSS property of any div (e.g. the matrix3d() on a DIV).